# Using the EN pin of the TPS259474ARPW efuse

Tags: voltage-divider, efuse

[TPS259474ARPW Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps25947.pdf?ts=1694783122600&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

I'm trying to figure out how to use the EN pin of the TPS259474ARPW efuse to accept the full VIN range (2.7V to 23V).

[image: TPS259474ARPW Schematic]

As per datasheet, the EN/UVLO pin :

Chapter 7.5 (Electrical Characteristics):

- enable the efuse if it rises over VUVLOR  (1.20V)
- disable the efuse if it falls below VUVLOF (1.09V)

Chapter 7.3 (Recommended Operating Conditions):

- should not exceed 5V

So I'm trying to find a voltage divider where:

- if VIN = 2.7V, EN >= 1.20V
- if VIN = 23V, EN <= 5V

Which is obviously impossible.

Am I missing something, or should I resort to voltage clamping or something ?

Comment: Try using a zener in conjunction with your divider.

Comment: what's the required voltage by your circuit/design to operate?

Comment: @Rodo, my design should work with anything between 4v and 23v as input.

Comment: I should have been more direct, sorry. Do you have a voltage regulator in your circuit?

Comment: @Rodo, yes, buck converters (3.3V & 1.8V) but they are protected by that efuse, so I can't use that rails to pull EN up (if it was what you were thinking of)

Comment: Don't the 3.3v and 1.8v have a max input voltage? is it really 24v?

Comment: @Rodo, It's 36v actually : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TPSM53603&ved=2ahUKEwjGue-ml7KBAxWEWaQEHVLeDkkQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2lbdt29PzND5-THH6v2E0S

Comment: The TPSM53603 seems to have a lot of the protections that you'll get with the eFuse. Except for reverse polarity. Maybe use a diode instead of the eFuse? At 3A you may need to pay attention to heat.